# jQuery(document).ready() won't work on AJAX loaded jQuery-UI widgets

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

I am loading some code with the jQuery.ajax() method. In this code I want to have some jQuery-UI Widgets (sliders and calenders) but they won't appear in IE.

Here some example code where you maybe can help me to understand where I am going wrong.

The Code which will load the jQuery-UI Widgets

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url: 'file.php',
    success: function (data) {
     jQuery('.somediv').empty().html(data); 
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

The Code which is loaded and SHOULD initialize the jQuery-UI Widgets

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.datepicker-div').datepicker(someoptions);
  jQuery('.slider-div').slider(someoptions);
});
</script>
<div class="datepicker-div">
<div class="slider-div">
```

You can see that it should be very simple. For FF it works fine but not for IE.

Maybe it has nothing to do with the document-ready statement?

Answer (score 3):

Just call the initializers in the success event:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url: 'file.php',
    success: function (data) {
      jQuery('.somediv').empty().html(data); 
      jQuery('.datepicker-div').datepicker(someoptions);
      jQuery('.slider-div').slider(someoptions);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Of course, you should refactor that by having a function for initializations:

```
function Initialize(){
  jQuery('.datepicker-div').datepicker(someoptions);
  jQuery('.slider-div').slider(someoptions);
}
```

Then have your success call it, as well as the `ready()` ebent:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url: 'file.php',
    success: function (data) {
     jQuery('.somediv').empty().html(data); 
     Initialize();
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

**Update**

I have read your question more carefully and now I fully understand it. Your `ready()` is in the loaded code. Then you should be using jQuery's [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

> ### ***Script Execution***
>
> When calling .load() using a URL without a suffixed selector
>   expression, the content is passed to .html() prior to scripts being
>   removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If
>   .load() is called with a selector expression appended to the URL,
>   however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated,
>   and thus are not executed. An example of both cases can be seen below:
>
> Here, any JavaScript loaded into #a as a part of the document will
>   successfully execute.
>
> `$('#a').load('article.html');`

Comment: Thanks for the help but the sliders and calenders would still not apear in IE. In the FF every thing works fine with load()

Comment: Try moving the `<script>` to the end of the loaded HTML and do not embed inside `ready()`, meaning it would be plain `<script>
jQuery('.datepicker-div').datepicker(someoptions);
jQuery('.slider-div').slider(someoptions);
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the scripts prior to appending the html, then adding them back.

```
var outHTML = data.replace(/<script>/ig,"<div class='script'>").replace(/<\/script>/ig,"</div>");
outHTML = $(outHTML);
var script = outHTML.find("div.script").detach();
$(".somediv").html(outHTML);
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.textContent = script.text();
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

Edit:

`.find("div.script")` may need to be changed to `.filter("div.script")` based on what your ajax request is returning.

Comment: Bevore trying that I would like to know why that should work. Sorry but I don't understand the purpose of that :S

Comment: Basically, it ensures that the scripts get ran after the DOM that you append is ready rather than before.

Comment: script.text() is empty with find() and filter().

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I didn't found out how i can solve the Problem, but i found a work around.

The work around is very simple. Because in every browser except for the IE the loading of the script via ajax works fine, we have to identify the IE and change the behaviour to not loading the script but redirect to the site I wanted to load. I am doing this all in Joomla 2.5, so there was a bit work to do but basically it was the following code wich solved the problem.

```
// preparing the url
// check for ie
if (jQuery.browser.msie) {
  window.location(url);
} else {
  // do the ajax
}
```